# KeyError: 'name' abi error on web3 Python

Tags: python, web3py

I'm trying to buy tokens using the swapExactTokensForTokens() Pancakeswap Router function), web3 imported in Python.

Problem 1: I keep getting an abi KeyError: 'name'. Here's my code and error below. I'm not sure how to handle this error.

problem 2: Is it possible to call the abi of a token without hardcoding it like I did below?

Code:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
import key
import time

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())
print("Block Number: ", web3.eth.blockNumber)

#My wallet address
sender_address = '0x111111111111111111111111111111111111'

#Pancakeswap router address instantiate and ABI code
panRouterContractAddress = '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'         
panAbi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"amountOut"}]'
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panAbi)

#Spend token instantiate and ABI
tokenToSpend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56")          #Contract address for purchase currency (BUSD)
spendAbi = '[{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'
spendTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(tokenToSpend, abi=spendAbi)                           #Spend token instance

#Contract address of token and amount to purchase
tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(input("Enter Token Address to buy: "))                    

#Input contract address for the token to purchase                                         
amountIn = web3.toWei(input("How much to spend? "), 'ether')                                  

#Amount of purchase currency to spend

#Trade execution (To accomodate fees, use the function: swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens)
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, [tokenToSpend,tokenToBuy], sender_address, (int(time.time()) + 1000000)).buildTransaction({   
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': amountIn, 
    'gas': 250000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),
    })  
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=key.private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print("Success!: " + web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

Error:

```
True
Block Number:  9762322
Enter Token Address to buy: 0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82
How much BUSD to spend? 1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Owner/Documents/BlockchainPy/MyCodes/test.py", line 30, in <module>
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, [tokenToSpend,tokenToBuy], sender_address, (int(time.time()) + 1000000)).buildTransaction({
   File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\sitepackages\web3\contract.py", line 876, in __call__clone._set_function_info()
   File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\sitepackages\web3\contract.py", line 881, in _set_function_info
  self.abi = find_matching_fn_abi(
   File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\contracts.py", line 127, in find_matching_fn_abi
   function_candidates = pipe(abi, name_filter, arg_count_filter, encoding_filter)
   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
        return c_pipe(data, funcs)
   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
        data = func(data)
   File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 93, in filter_by_name
         return [
   File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BlockchainPy\lib\sitepackages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 99, in <listcomp> and abi['name'] == name
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas The error message above is the full message and starts with the word "Traceback (most recent call last)".

Comment: Normally full error message doesn't end on `and abi['name'] == name` but it has something more.

Comment: You're right @furas my mistake. I was missing this part `KeyError: 'name' `. The error message has been updated to show that.

Comment: @furas hey bud, I may need your help again :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719586/getamountsout-function-with-web3-py-returns-wrong-amount]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error shows problem in line `99` in file `abi.py` with key `abi["name"]` so I found this file (you have full path in error) and add `print()` before line `99` to see all `abi` used in this place

```
def filter_by_name(name: str, contract_abi: ABI) -> List[Union[ABIFunction, ABIEvent]]:

    for abi in contract_abi:
        print(abi)
        print('---')

    # ... rest ...
```

and it shows me

```
{'stateMutability': 'payable', 'type': 'amountOut'}
```

which doesn't have `"name": ...` and this makes problem.

If you check `panAbi = ...` then you see this `{'stateMutability': ...}` at the end.

If I add ie.`"name": ""` in this `{'stateMutability': ...}` in `panAbi` then it resolves problem but I don't know what real `name` it should have.

Comment: Adding `"name": ""` at the end of ` {'stateMutability': ...}` solves that problem, I just left the name blank. Thanks, buddy! Any idea on how to solve "Problem 2"?

Comment: I don't know which code you means in "Problem 2" but you can use `input()` to ask for data or read from file or uses `sys.args` to get it in command line. You can also display list of tokens and ask for number to get token from list. And you can also create GUI using tkinter, PyQt, etc. You can also put code in function with arguments and run it with different arguments.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to a function(or otherwise) for calling abi rather than hardcoding it as I did above. The router abi (`panAbi`) is fine hardcoded as it will hardly change. However, I may need to change `tokenToSpend` often and will have to copy and paste the corresponding abi (`spendAbi`) every time. So I was wondering if there's a way to call it so that it fetches it automatically for whatever token contract is defined as `tokenToSpend`. Something like: `spendAbi = tokenToSpend.functions.abi().call()` (This is definitely wrong but just to give you an idea of what I'm looking for).

Comment: Also, is the abi for most tokens the same? If the answer is yes, then I may not need to change it at all unless it throws an error. Another idea might be to fetch it from bscscan.com website with a query or something like that.

Comment: I never use this module so I don't know if it need different values. But you could keep them in dictionary and select from dictionary based on other values. OR create functions with hardcoded values and then use these functions and you don't have to copy it again and again.

Comment: I see...that's a great suggestion, thanks. I'll try that. Seems like the abi keys I need for my code are common and work with most tokens that I've tried, so I may not need to change it at all. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem 2: in general, you don't need to know any ABI, you can ask bscscan to return it for you.
This is the code (use the switch DEBUG to select between testnet and mainnet).
Set your BSC API key in place of bscAPIkey

```
import requests
import json

def GetABI (Address):
    if DEBUG:
        url_eth = "https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
        API_ENDPOINT = url_eth+"?module=contract&action=getabi&address="+str(Address)+"&apikey="+bscAPIkey
        resp = requests.get(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers)
    else:
        url_eth = "https://api.bscscan.com/api"
        API_ENDPOINT = url_eth+"?module=contract&action=getabi&address="+str(Address)+"&apikey="+bscAPIkey
        resp = requests.get(url = API_ENDPOINT)

    res = json.loads(resp.text)
    status = int(res['status'])
    if status:
        response = resp.json()
        abi=json.loads(response["result"])
        return abi
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This is quite helpful. It's a pretty neat way to keep my script clutter-free of long abi codes. Thank you!

Comment: yes, really helpful... i am trying this as well. Can I check/confirm what 'address' refers to in the GetABI(Address) is? Is it the contract address of the 'tobuy' token, or my wallet-address? @luca

Comment: @Kiann: Whatever smart contract on the blockchain has an ABI (Application Binary Interface), which provides the "input door" to interact with it, and this function returns this ABI. What 'address' you have to use depends on what you are doing. If you are transferring a token, it will be the address of the token, if you are swapping a liquid pair, it will be the smart contract of the swapping service, ...

Comment: @Kiann: Usually, after GetABI you will call mycontract=web3.eth.contract(address, abi) to get the smart contract itself and finally mycontract.functions.<CONTRACTFUNCTION> to interact with the smart contract performing the CONTRACTFUNCTION operation. The Address you should use in GetABI is the one you will call on web3.eth.contract afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i fix it:

```
contract_abi = json.loads('[{"type":"constructor","stateMutability":"nonpayable","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"_factory","internalType":"address"},{"type":"address","name":"_WETH","internalType":"address"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"view","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"","internalType":"address"}],"name":"WETH","inputs":[]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountA","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountB","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"tokenA","internalType":"address"},{"type":"address","name":"tokenB","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"payable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountToken","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETH","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"view","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"","internalType":"address"}],"name":"factory","inputs":[]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"pure","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"pure","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"view","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"view","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"pure","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountB","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountA","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveA","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"reserveB","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountA","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountB","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"tokenA","internalType":"address"},{"type":"address","name":"tokenB","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountToken","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETH","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETH","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountToken","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETH","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"bool","name":"approveMax","internalType":"bool"},{"type":"uint8","name":"v","internalType":"uint8"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"r","internalType":"bytes32"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"s","internalType":"bytes32"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETH","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"bool","name":"approveMax","internalType":"bool"},{"type":"uint8","name":"v","internalType":"uint8"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"r","internalType":"bytes32"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"s","internalType":"bytes32"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountA","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountB","internalType":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"tokenA","internalType":"address"},{"type":"address","name":"tokenB","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"liquidity","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"bool","name":"approveMax","internalType":"bool"},{"type":"uint8","name":"v","internalType":"uint8"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"r","internalType":"bytes32"},{"type":"bytes32","name":"s","internalType":"bytes32"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"payable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"payable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"payable","outputs":[],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountIn","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"function","stateMutability":"nonpayable","outputs":[{"type":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","internalType":"uint256[]"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"amountOut","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","internalType":"uint256"},{"type":"address[]","name":"path","internalType":"address[]"},{"type":"address","name":"to","internalType":"address"},{"type":"uint256","name":"deadline","internalType":"uint256"}]},{"type":"receive","stateMutability":"payable"}]')

# Every entry in ABI must have "name" attribute! Otherwise web3.py will fail when you call contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(1, [my_wallet_address], my_wallet_address, deadline)
i : int = 0
for entry in contract_abi:
    if 'name' not in entry:
        entry['name'] = f"dummy_name_{i}"
        i = i+1
```